# BoundingBox does not rotate with the group

Tags: three.js

I have this problem: I rotate the object group, but the BoundingBox does not rotate with the group. And I don’t know what the problem is.

I would be grateful for your help!

Code:

```
createGroup() {
...creation elements for group

    const group = new THREE.Group();

    group.add(elements);
 
    box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(group, true);

    scene.add(group)
}

rotateGroup() {
  group.rotation.x -= 0.1;
  createNewBoxBounding()
}

createNewBoxBounding() {
  group.updateMatrix();
  box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(group, true);
}
```

Comment: Box3() is AABB (axis-aligned bounding box)

Comment: What can I replace it with?

Comment: Use OBB (oriented bounding box): https://threejs.org/examples/?q=obb#webgl_math_obb